# Button or text in cell ultragrid C#

Tags: c#, button, cell, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I've done an ultragrid that expands line by line, but I have to put a little button on top or a text "see more ..." below that indicates it can be expanded, but so far I've only been able to put a button on a Separate column, which is not pretty.

I want something like the facebook news feed, has anyone done something like this?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is set [Description](http://www.infragistics.com/help/winforms/infragistics4.win.ultrawingrid.v16.2~infragistics.win.ultrawingrid.ultragridrow~description) on each row, e.g. in InitializeRow event, and then turn on AutoPreviewArea by setting [AutoPreviewEnabled](http://www.infragistics.com/help/winforms/infragistics4.win.ultrawingrid.v16.2~infragistics.win.ultrawingrid.ultragridband~autopreviewenabled) to true like this:

```
private void ultraGrid1_InitializeLayout(object sender, InitializeLayoutEventArgs e)
{
    e.Layout.Bands[0].AutoPreviewEnabled = true;
}

private void UltraGrid1_InitializeRow(object sender, InitializeRowEventArgs e)
{
    e.Row.Description = "Bar and Foo";
}
```

This will show a nice description under each row. Note that, if the row's Description is empty string no preview will be shown. So you may handle [BeforeRowExpanded](http://www.infragistics.com/help/winforms/infragistics4.win.ultrawingrid.v16.2~infragistics.win.ultrawingrid.ultragrid~beforerowexpanded_ev) event and set the row's description to an empty string, and in [BeforeRowCollapsed](http://www.infragistics.com/help/winforms/infragistics4.win.ultrawingrid.v16.2~infragistics.win.ultrawingrid.ultragrid~beforerowcollapsed_ev) envet to set back the row's description to whatever you need.

Comment: Is a good idea, but the text is below the first column, is there a way to put in a specific cell?